# Getting tweet replies to a particular tweet from the tweet author

Tags: api, curl, twitter, tweets

I am trying to get tweet replies for a particular Tweet/TwitterThread that are just from the author of the Tweet only. So far, I am able to get all the replies for a particular Tweet by using the search endpoint like this:

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=conversation_id:1373848915464785920&tweet.fields=in_reply_to_user_id,author_id,created_at,conversation_id' --header 'Authorization: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN'
```

The code above gives me ALL the replies. What I want is only the replies from the original author.

For reference, this is the documentation link for the code above: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/conversation-id

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the author in the query with "(from:mark)" assuming the username is mark. Say the following is the query: "apples -filter:replies"
Then, the following would be the query including the author of the tweet: "apples (from:mark) -filter:replies"